# How to unload a keras/tensorflow model from memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Here's the problem: My (Keras)model is listening to a task queue. If no task arrives in 10 min, I want to unload the model and free the memory.

But I never thought such a job would be so hard...

Here are some failed tries:

(1) Set `model = None`, hope GC collect the memory.

(2) `del model`

(3) Use `K.clear_session()`, `tf.reset_defualt_graph()`.

(4) Any combination of above methods followed by calling `gc.collect()` manually.

Is it possible to unload a model from memory without exiting current process? Any other suggestions?

Comment: from this issue - https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2102 it seems that downgrading is one solution to this problem

Comment: Never thought that the way to solve the problem is "downgrading..."
So sad..

Comment: Of course, sometimes it's necessary to downgrade when future versions are not stable or bugs are found causing the latest versions not to behave correctly. Also you'll find that some libraries do not support certain versions of other libraries, or even Python, and you will have to downgrade.

I put it as a comment because as you say this isn't really the 'answer', but more of a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

[numba library](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.13/CUDADevice.html)

Assuming you are using device 0

```
from numba import cuda
cuda.select_device(0)
cuda.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is:

```
import keras
keras.backend.clear_session()
```

As far as I know it clears the memory